# FreeImageNet Save TIFF_CCITTFAX3 or TIFF_CCITTFAX4 does not work

Tags: c#, tiff, freeimage

Compression in TIFF_CCITTFAX3 or TIFF_CCITTFAX4 does not work properly, the resulting file is always in TIFF_LZW format

Ex :

```
FreeImage.Save(FREE_IMAGE_FORMAT.FIF_TIFF, dib, outFileName, FREE_IMAGE_SAVE_FLAGS.TIFF_CCITTFAX3);
```

how to solve this problem ?

Thanks
Njara

Comment: Is your DIB 1 bit per pixel? FreeImageNet may be using a fallback compression if you feed it the wrong bit depth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to convert color image to monochrome before saving

```
//dib = FreeImage.Threshold(dib, 128);
dib = FreeImage.Dither(dib, FREE_IMAGE_DITHER.FID_CLUSTER6x6);
//dib = FreeImage.ConvertColorDepth(dib, FREE_IMAGE_COLOR_DEPTH.FICD_01_BPP);
FreeImage.Save(FREE_IMAGE_FORMAT.FIF_TIFF, dib, outFileName, FREE_IMAGE_SAVE_FLAGS.TIFF_CCITTFAX4);
```

Thanks